# How would I go about selecting more columns with this query

Tags: c#, mysql

I just need to know how I would place more table columns in this query, like `major` ect.

Thank you!

```
MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM student", conn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder sqlCmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adap);
            DataSet sqlSet = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(sqlSet, "studentNumber");
            conn.Close();
            return sqlSet;
```

EDIT:

I think I asked the question wrong, I dont want entries from another table..I need the following.

I have a table called `student`, in this table I have 4 columns, one of them being `studentNumber` another being `major` another `gradePointAverage`. How to I add these columns into the code above?

EDIT NUMBER 2:

I know how to do the SELECT statement, I was more looking for help on this section `adap.Fill(sqlSet, "studentNumber");` How do I put the `major` column into that?

Answer (score 0):

use below query

```
select students.*,table2.major from student inner join table2 on student.it = table2.id
```

Comment: I dont think I asked the question correctly.. about to make an edit

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the columns names as below

```
"SELECT studentNumber,major   FROM student"
```

since you have `*` that means select all the columns, your code will return all the table columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use join query to select more column but only if the column names are same in both table
below is query
SELECT t1.column AS column1, t2.column AS column2
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.column = t2.column

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table called student, in this table I have 4 columns, one of
>   them being studentNumber another being major another
>   gradePointAverage. How to I add these columns into the code above?

So select your columns in your query.

Change

```
MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM student", conn);
```

to

```
MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT studentNumber, major FROM student", conn);
```